# How to add objects to arraylist with another class?

Tags: java, arraylist

Basically my professor told me to make use of arraylist? I don't get his point to be honest.. i think he wants me to add objects to arraylist? which right now, I really have no idea how to do it..

My code is running and is really fine. However, he still wanted me to make use of arraylist to make it look better?

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
       package ahaprogram2;

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class AhaProgram {

  public static Container container1 = new Container("Container 1: ");
public static Container container2 = new Container("Container 2: ");
public static Container container3 = new Container("Container 3: ");
public static Container container4 = new Container("Container 4: ");
public static Container container5 = new Container("Container 5: ");
public static boolean loop = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {



    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello! This is the AHA Program of Jalosjos, 
   Parreno and Alfonso");
    System.out.println("Please type the letter of your option");



    while (loop != true) {

        showOptions();
        InputHandler();

    }
}

public static void InputHandler() {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
     String optionletter = reader.nextLine();
    if (optionletter.equals("A")) {  // OPTION A
            System.out.println("There are 5 containers.. What container 
    will you name? ");
            System.out.print("Type the number of your container: ");
            String contInput = reader.nextLine();

            if (contInput.equals("1")) {
                System.out.print("Input the name of Container 1: ");
                String ContInp1 = reader.nextLine();
                container1.renameCont(ContInp1);                    
                container1.printContainer();

            } else if (contInput.equals("2")) {
                System.out.print("Input the name of Container 2: ");
                String ContInp2 = reader.nextLine();
                container2.renameCont(ContInp2);                    
                container2.printContainer();
            } else if (contInput.equals("3")) {
                System.out.print("Input the name of Container 3: ");
                String ContInp3 = reader.nextLine();
                container3.renameCont(ContInp3);                    
                container3.printContainer();
            } else if (contInput.equals("4")) {
                System.out.print("Input the name of Container 4: ");
                String ContInp4 = reader.nextLine();
                container4.renameCont(ContInp4);                    
                container4.printContainer();

            } else if (contInput.equals("5")) {
                System.out.print("Input the name of Container 5: ");
                String ContInp5 = reader.nextLine();
                container5.renameCont(ContInp5);                    
                container5.printContainer();
            }

        }

        if (optionletter.equals("B")) {    // for option B
            System.out.println("Which container will you use?");
            System.out.print("Type a number for the container: ");
            String contforAdd = reader.nextLine();

            if (contforAdd.equals("1")) {

                System.out.print("How many cans will you add?: ");
                int numofCans1 = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

                for (int i = 0; i < numofCans1; i++) {
                    System.out.print("Enter the name of Can " + (i + 1) + 
          " : ");
                    String CanName = reader.nextLine();
                    container1.AddCan(CanName);

                }
                System.out.println("**CANS ADDED SUCCESSFULLY**");
            }

            if (contforAdd.equals("2")) {

                System.out.print("How many cans will you add?: ");
                int numofCans2 = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

                for (int i = 0; i < numofCans2; i++) {
                    System.out.print("Enter the name of Can " + (i + 1) + 
           " : ");
                    String CanName = reader.nextLine();
                    container2.AddCan(CanName);

                }
                System.out.println("**CANS ADDED SUCCESSFULLY**");
            }

            if (contforAdd.equals("3")) {

                System.out.print("How many cans will you add?: ");
                int numofCans3 = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

                for (int i = 0; i < numofCans3; i++) {
                    System.out.print("Enter the name of Can " + (i + 1) + 
          " : ");
                    String CanName = reader.nextLine();
                    container3.AddCan(CanName);

                }
                System.out.println("**CANS ADDED SUCCESSFULLY**");
            }
            if (contforAdd.equals("4")) {

                System.out.print("How many cans will you add?: ");
                int numofCans4 = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

                for (int i = 0; i < numofCans4; i++) {
                    System.out.print("Enter the name of Can " + (i + 1) + 
            " : ");
                    String CanName = reader.nextLine();
                    container4.AddCan(CanName);

                }
                System.out.println("**CANS ADDED SUCCESSFULLY**");
            }

            if (contforAdd.equals("5")) {

                System.out.print("How many cans will you add?: ");
                int numofCans5 = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

                for (int i = 0; i < numofCans5; i++) {
                    System.out.print("Enter the name of Can " + (i + 1) + 
              " : ");
                    String CanName = reader.nextLine();
                    container5.AddCan(CanName);

                }
                System.out.println("**CANS ADDED SUCCESSFULLY**");
            }

        }

        if (optionletter.equals("C")) {                
            System.out.println("Which container will you use?");
            System.out.print("Type a number for the container: ");
            String contforRemove = reader.nextLine();

            if (contforRemove.equals("1")) {                    
                System.out.print("What can will you remove?: ");
                String canRemove = reader.nextLine();
                container1.RemoveCan(canRemove);
            }

            if (contforRemove.equals("2")) {                    
                System.out.print("What can will you remove?: ");
                String canRemove = reader.nextLine();
                container2.RemoveCan(canRemove);
            }

            if (contforRemove.equals("3")) {                    
                System.out.print("What can will you remove?: ");
                String canRemove = reader.nextLine();
                container3.RemoveCan(canRemove);
            }

            if (contforRemove.equals("4")) {                    
                System.out.print("What can will you remove?: ");
                String canRemove = reader.nextLine();
                container4.RemoveCan(canRemove);
            }

            if (contforRemove.equals("5")) {                    
                System.out.print("What can will you remove?: ");
                String canRemove = reader.nextLine();
                container5.RemoveCan(canRemove);
            }


        }  

        if (optionletter.equals("D")) {
            showOptionsDisplay();
            System.out.print("Type a letter: ");
            String letterDisplay = reader.nextLine();

            if (letterDisplay.equals("A")) {
                container1.printContents();
                System.out.println("");
            }

            if (letterDisplay.equals("B")) {
                container2.printContents();
                System.out.println("");
            }

            if (letterDisplay.equals("C")) {
                container3.printContents();
                System.out.println("");
            }

            if (letterDisplay.equals("D")) {
                container4.printContents();
                System.out.println("");
            }

            if (letterDisplay.equals("E")) {
                container5.printContents();
                System.out.println("");
            }

            if (letterDisplay.equals("F")) {
                container1.printContents();
                System.out.println("");
                container2.printContents();
                System.out.println("");
                container3.printContents();
                System.out.println("");
                container4.printContents();
                System.out.println("");
                container5.printContents();
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }

        if (optionletter.equals("E")) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Thank you for using our program. MWAH!");
            loop = true;
        }

         }

       public static void showOptions() {
    System.out.println("A = Name Containers");
    System.out.println("B = Add Cans");
    System.out.println("C = Remove Cans");
    System.out.println("D = Display Cans");
    System.out.println("E = Quit");
    System.out.print("Type a Letter: ");
     }

    public static void showOptionsDisplay() {
    System.out.println("Pick an Option");
    System.out.println("A = Display container 1");
    System.out.println("B = Display container 2");
    System.out.println("C = Display container 3");
    System.out.println("D = Display container 4");
    System.out.println("E = Display container 5");
    System.out.println("F = Display all containers"); 
    }

     }
```

Here is the other class

```
     package ahaprogram2;

     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Container {
 Scanner reader  = new Scanner(System.in);
 public ArrayList<String> CanContainer = new ArrayList<String>();
 public int Contsizep;
 public String contName;
 public String changeName;



 public Container(String contname){
     this.contName = contname;

 }

 public void AddCan(String CantoAdd) {
     this.CanContainer.add(CantoAdd);
 }

 public void RemoveCan(String CantoRemove) {
      if (this.CanContainer.contains(CantoRemove)) {

        this.CanContainer.remove(CantoRemove);  
          System.out.println("** " + CantoRemove + " Can removed 
     successfully**");
     }
      else {
          System.out.println("Can cannot be found.. make sure to put the 
      exact name!!");
      } 

       }

    public void renameCont(String changename) {
    this.contName += changename;
    }

     public void printContents() {
     System.out.println("Here are the contents of " + contName);
     System.out.println("");
     for(String counter : this.CanContainer){

        System.out.println(counter); }


       }

      public void printContainer() {  // for OPTION A ONLY
     System.out.println("CONTAINER NAME SUCCESSFUL: ** " + contName + 
   "**");
   }
   }
```

I just would like to put everything to an arraylist 
please help.. again my professor doesn't teach us face to face that's why 
I'm really trying my best to watch videos in youtube and to ask here also..

Comment: [tag:Javascript] question tag removed -- your question has nothing to do with this programming language, and you definitely do not want to annoy the JS experts by bringing them to this question.

Comment: Having said that, your question is best answered by finding and reading an ArrayList tutorial, since you're asking about basic use of this key core Java tool, and this site does not function well as a substitute for these tutorials. Much luck!

Comment: "I don't get his point to be honest." - well, without knowing what exactly your professor told you it is hard for us to get _his_ point as well. Maybe it would be better to go ask him yourself and if you still don't get him ask him to explain in more simple terms or show you an example of what he means.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of your code seems to predicate on interacting one of five `Container` objects in similar (if not identical) ways. To start, you can use an ArrayList to store a list of Container objects, instead of manually declaring each container:

```
public static ArrayList<Container> containerList = new ArrayList<Container>();
```

You can then populate this list with new containers using [`ArrayList.add(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-), combined with a for loop or some other construct:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  Container container = new Container("Container " + i + ": ");
  containerList.add(container);
}
```

Likewise, you can access any particular container using [`ArrayList.get(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) (if you know the index) or [`ArrayList.indexOf(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) (if you have a reference to a specific container). This can replace or supplement your conditional statements. For instance, your list of `(contInput.equals("X"))` statements could be replaced with:

```
int index = Integer.parseInt(contInput);
System.out.print("Input the name of Container " + index + ": ");
Container container = containerList.get(index - 1); // arrays start at 0, but your numbering starts at 1

String contImp = reader.nextLine();
container.renameCont(contImp);
container.printContainer();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your containers to ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<Container> containers = new ArrayList<>();
containers.add(new Container("Container 1: "));
containers.add(new Container("Container 2: "));
containers.add(new Container("Container 3: "));
```

then get them like this:

```
Container firstContainer = containers.get(0);
Container secondContainer = containers.get(1);
```